# Current location not showing first-time when I open Google map activity

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created a project in that I used google maps to show the current location on map but my issue is when first time open maps activity showing wrong location

Comment: can you show code

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission and enabled Location on your phone.

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Comment: Ya I already given  here first time mean if I kill the app and again open the app that time showing wrong if second time open from other activity to map activity that time no issue